# What set of rules say that scratching requires the player to take another ball out of a pocket?

Tags: rules, pool

From time to time I stumble upon pool players who think/thought the rule is to take a ball (other than the cue ball) out of the pocket every time you scratch but none of them knew where that rule came from. We're playing 8-ball here.

Is this a real rule or a myth? and if the former than what set of rules does it apply to?

Comment: "the rule is to take **a ball** out of the pocket every time you scratch" Which ball? The cue ball? Or another ball?

Comment: Another ball, this is in an 8-ball game

Comment: Glad @edmastermind29 asked for clarification. I've definitely never heard this though. Must be some strange *house rule*, or bizarre league rule.

Comment: @NicholasV. that's what I concluded but got curious to find out if such official rule exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this does happen in both Bank Pool and One Pocket.

From [section 5 of the bank pool rules](http://www.onepocket.org/BankPoolRules.htm),

> 5.2 Any scratch or foul ends the shooter’s inning, and a penalty of one ball is charged.

Comment: Well done buddy! But it also oddly refers to WPA General Rules at the start, which doesn't agree on foul cost. "3.9 Standard Fouls 
If the shooter commits a foul, play passes to his opponent. The cue ball is in hand, and the incoming player may place it anywhere on the playing surface." However, BCA does [agree with this answer](http://www.playbca.com/portals/0/rules/bank.pdf), as far as BankPool Rules

Comment: I thought the question was about 8-ball.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a standard rule. According to the World Pool-Billiard Association [rules](http://www.wpa-pool.com/web/the_rules_of_play), the only penalty for a foul is the following

> 3.9 Standard Fouls
>   If the shooter commits a foul, play passes to his opponent. The cue ball is in hand, and the incoming player may place it anywhere on the playing surface. (See 1.5 Cue Ball in Hand.)

The rule further specifies that no object ball other than the 8-ball is ever spotted (rule3.7). The Billiard Congress of America (BCA) uses the above rules.

*Edited this section after finding APA rules online*
The American Poolplayers Association [8-ball rules](http://www.poolplaying.com/8ballrules.htm) do specify that object balls are spotted *if they have been knocked on the floor (Rule 6)*. An object ball knocked on the floor is not a foul, but it is spotted after the player's shot is complete or after he misses, whichever comes later.

This is Rule 6

> 1. BALL ON THE FLOOR -- If the 8-ball is knocked on the floor , it is loss of game. Object balls knocked on the floor are spotted. If the spot is taken, the ball is placed on a line directly behind the spot as close as possible. Knocking a ball other than the cue ball on the floor is not a foul. It might occur that a player pockets his ball while simultaneously knocking another ball on the floor. In the situation, it is still his turn and the ball is not spotted until he misses. If the ball on the floor is one of the shooter's balls, it is spotted when the shooter had pocketed all his other balls or misses.

Both sets of rules agree with respect to the original question. Pocketed object balls are not spotted after a foul (scratch or any other type of foul).

On the other hand, there are myriad house rules that I've played by: 8-ball on break, loser pays $5; 8-ball on break loses game; All shots must be called; Pull object balls on scratch; No combination shots; Combination shots can use opponent's object ball; etc. There are probably as many house rules as there are places to play. So to answer your question - Yes, it is a rule *in that pool-hall with those players*. But it is not an official standard rule.

Comment: Yes, these are the two set of rules I follow, APA and BCA and neither do show anything about it. The question was, does there exist a set of rules that include that rule? There are more rules than APA and BCA out there

Comment: There are myriad house rules that I've played by: 8-ball on break, loser pays $5; 8-ball on break loses game; All shots must be called; Pull object balls on scratch; No combination shots; Combination shots can use opponent's object ball; etc. There are probably as many house rules as there are places to play. So to answer your question - Yes, it is a rule *in that pool-hall with those players*. But it is not an official standard rule anywhere.

Comment: Agreed, you should add that to your answer

Answer (score -2):

It isn't a myth, since that is the rule I always played casual 8-ball with in bars or rec-rooms here in the USA.  In fact, I never ran into anyone playing by other rules.

It is helpful when everyone is really bad because it gives you something to shoot at, and the game lasts longer.  On the other hand, when just the cue ball and the 8 is left it gets pretty scary because then scratching loses you the game.

Comment: Can you point us to the rule book in which it states so, else they're merely house rules?

Comment: No, these are just the rules everyone 'knows'.  If someone put them in a book later, that's not how they came about.

Comment: Sorry that doesn't count as an official rule. I used to think hitting 3 cushions was foul-free only later to find out that it was a myth and in reality (APA and BCA) it is a foul and a ball-in-hand

Comment: I disagree with your assertion that games using rules in common use are 'mythological'.  If they exist, they are real. Just as real as those sanctioned by APA.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, and I think it's a worth raising in Sports Meta

Comment: It may be worth investigating the origins/history of this "understood" rule? If it exists, means it's real, but it doesn't always mean it's documented. Perhaps there's a reason pool is played this way? Just food for thought more than anything here.